# Radius Values not Displaying in (List)PolarPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm having troubles with the `PolarAxes` option in `ListPolarPlot` under Mathematica 8.0.  To be more specific, when I run the following:

```
z1 = Import["01_01-rshoulder-deg-1.mat"];
ListPolarPlot[z1, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 750}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 20}, 
PolarAxes -> True, PolarTicks -> {{0, "0%"}, {Pi/12, "4.16%"}, {Pi/6, "8.33%"}, {Pi/4, "12.5%"}, {Pi/3, "16.67%"}, {5 Pi/12, "20.83%"}, {Pi/2, "25%"}, {Pi/12 + Pi/2, "29.16%"}, {Pi/6 + Pi/2, "33.33%"}, {Pi/4 + Pi/2, "37.5%"}, {Pi/3 + Pi/2, "41.67%"}, {5 Pi/12 + Pi/2, "45.83%"}, {Pi/2 + Pi/2, "50%"}, {Pi/12 + 2 Pi/2, "54.16%"}, {Pi/6 + 2 Pi/2, "58.33%"}, {Pi/4 + 2 Pi/2, "62.5%"}, {Pi/3 + 2 Pi/2, "66.67%"}, {5 Pi/12 + 2 Pi/2, "70.83%"}, {Pi/2 + 2 Pi/2, "75%"}, , {Pi/12 + 3 Pi/2, "79.16%"}, {Pi/6 + 3 Pi/2, "83.33%"}, {Pi/4 + 3 Pi/2, "87.5%"}, {Pi/3 + 3 Pi/2, "91.67%"}, {5 Pi/12 + 3 Pi/2, "95.83%"}, Automatic},
PolarGridLines -> True, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Thick, Gray], 
PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.0125], ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
PlotLabel -> Style["Right Shoulder\n Region Joint Angle", 55, 
LineSpacing -> {0.9, 0}]]
```

The corresponding polar plot is being truncated:

[image: Truncated polar plot]

My guess is that Mathematica is only displaying the relevant plotted component.  When I changed `PolarAxes` to `PolarAxes -> Automatic`, the issue is fixed.  However, I lose the values for the radius of the plot:

[image: Non-truncated polar plot]

Is there an option that I can add to the `ListPolarPlot` command so that it still displays the radius values and without having to specify each value manually?

The corresponding dataset can be downloaded from: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpt01ary5ws4j0i/01_01-rshoulder-deg-1.mat

Comment: Will `PlotRange -> All` in your first plot work?

Comment: Additionally I was unable to reproduce this in version 10.0.0 under Windows.  Would you include your data to make sure it's not specific to that?

Comment: In response to Silvia: no, it didn't work.  In response to Mr. Wizard's request, I've provided a download link in my original post.  I'll also see if my lab can't purchase a Mathematica 10 license, if the issue is due to some bug in Mathematica 8.

Comment: Have you tried `PlotRange -> Full`?

Answer (score 4):

Set a *specific* plot range, like `PlotRange -> {{-0.12,0.12},{-0.1,0.1}}`.  Then,

```
z1 = Import["01_01-rshoulder-deg-1.mat"];
ListPolarPlot[z1, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 750}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 20}, 
 PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {{0, "0%"}, {Pi/12, "4.16%"}, {Pi/6, "8.33%"}, {Pi/4, 
    "12.5%"}, {Pi/3, "16.67%"}, {5 Pi/12, "20.83%"}, {Pi/2, 
    "25%"}, {Pi/12 + Pi/2, "29.16%"}, {Pi/6 + Pi/2, 
    "33.33%"}, {Pi/4 + Pi/2, "37.5%"}, {Pi/3 + Pi/2, 
    "41.67%"}, {5 Pi/12 + Pi/2, "45.83%"}, {Pi/2 + Pi/2, 
    "50%"}, {Pi/12 + 2 Pi/2, "54.16%"}, {Pi/6 + 2 Pi/2, 
    "58.33%"}, {Pi/4 + 2 Pi/2, "62.5%"}, {Pi/3 + 2 Pi/2, 
    "66.67%"}, {5 Pi/12 + 2 Pi/2, "70.83%"}, {Pi/2 + 2 Pi/2, 
    "75%"}, , {Pi/12 + 3 Pi/2, "79.16%"}, {Pi/6 + 3 Pi/2, 
    "83.33%"}, {Pi/4 + 3 Pi/2, "87.5%"}, {Pi/3 + 3 Pi/2, 
    "91.67%"}, {5 Pi/12 + 3 Pi/2, "95.83%"}, Automatic}, 
 PolarGridLines -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{-0.12, 0.12}, {-0.1, 0.1}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Thick, Gray], 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.0125], ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Right Shoulder\n Region Joint Angle", 55, 
   LineSpacing -> {0.9, 0}]]
```

[image]